# How to fix error validation split in MLP using Keras?

Tags: keras, neural-network, text-classification, mlp

I'm newbie in Neural Network. I'm going to do a text classification research using MLP model with keras. Input layer consisting of 900 nodes, 2 hidden layers, and 2 outputs.

The code I use is as follows:

```
#Split data training & testing (90:10)
Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = model_selection.train_test_split(dataset['review'],dataset['sentimen'],test_size=0.2, random_state=8)

Encoder = LabelEncoder()

Train_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Train_Y)
Test_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Test_Y)

Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=None)
Tfidf_vect.fit(dataset['review'])
Train_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Train_X)
Test_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Test_X)

#ANN Architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 100, activation = 'sigmoid',  input_shape=(32, 900)))
model.add(Dense(units = 100, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid'))
opt = Adam (learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = opt, 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

#Hyperparameter
epochs= 100
batch_size= 32
es = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",mode='min',patience=10)
model_prediction = model.fit(Train_X_Tfidf, Train_Y, epochs=epochs, 
                             batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, 
                             validation_split=0.1, callbacks =[es])
```

But getting Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in train_validation_split(arrays, validation_split)
   1478   unsplitable = [type(t) for t in flat_arrays if not _can_split(t)]
   1479   if unsplitable:
-> 1480     raise ValueError(
   1481         "`validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy "
   1482         "arrays, found following types in the input: {}".format(unsplitable))

ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>]
```

How to Fix it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo: `dataset['sentimen']` -> `dataset['sentiment']`? This could explain the error.

Comment: I'm sure, dataset['sentimen'] is correct, because it is not in English

Comment: Actually now that I'm looking at this more closely I see several weird points. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with NNs so I'm not sure about it. 1) the `Test_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Test_Y)` is probably messing your labels, it should be `Encoder.transform(Test_Y)`. 2) I'm surprised that people use TFIDF with NNs, did you see this somewhere? Usually word embeddings are used as input. 3) with TFIDF you should remove rare words. 4) you have data leakage since you fit the tfidf encoding on the whole data. 5) the error is caused by the wrong type of array passed as input, I assume this is ...

Comment: .. about `Train_X_Tfidf, Train_Y`. Apparently one of these or both would have some scipy sparse matrix type and this is not correct. I don't see this in the code so I don't know exactly, but maybe you can check the type of these inputs.